# Configuring Spring Boot Security to use BCrypt password encoding in Grails 3.0

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-boot, bcrypt, grails-3.0

In Grails 3.0, how do you specify that Spring Boot Security should use **BCrypt** for password encoding?

The following lines should provide a sense of what I think needs to be done (but I'm mostly just guessing):

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder

passwordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder)
```

My application loads `spring-boot-starter-security` as a dependency:

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
```

And I have a service wired up for `userDetailsService` using:

**conf/spring/resources.groovy**

```
import com.example.GormUserDetailsService
import com.example.SecurityConfig

beans = {
   webSecurityConfiguration(SecurityConfig)
   userDetailsService(GormUserDetailsService)
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have the following code in `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy`

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

beans = {
    bcryptEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder)
}
```

and I have a java file which does the configuration as described by `spring-security`. It should be possible to do it in groovy too, but I did it in java.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bcryptEncoder;

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService myDetailsService

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            // userDetailsService should be changed to your user details service
            // password encoder being the bean defined in grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
            auth.userDetailsService(myDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bcryptEncoder);
    }
}
```