# Spring Boot, MySQL: How to do a database authentication with a hashed password?

Tags: java, hash, spring-security, spring-boot, password-encryption

Hello I have a Spring Boot application, which only has 1 Admin and no users. 
I already created a Table called: "administrator" which contains the username and a String with the hashed password. (I put the password in a converter to do so.)

Now my question is **what I should change** in the `WebSecurityConfiguration.java` so that the code checks the hash in my database with the String I've written in the login form to be able to log in.

My code:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");

 }
```

I found the following but I still don't really know what to do:

- [Switching from MD5 to BCrypt with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285604/switching-from-md5-to-bcrypt-with-spring-security?rq=1)
- http://kielczewski.eu/2014/12/spring-boot-security-application/
- [Configuring Spring Boot Security to use BCrypt password encoding in Grails 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490862/configuring-spring-boot-security-to-use-bcrypt-password-encoding-in-grails-3-0)

Comment: Did you read the doc? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-jdbc

Comment: I looked at it but it doesn't really show how to do the authentication. I read that I need to code end encode the password. But I don't know what changes I have to do, that it codes my password defined in the WebSecurity, saves it in the database and is able to encode it from the db, when I try to autheticate.

Comment: see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ for example and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521251/spring-securitypassword-encoding-in-db-and-in-applicationcontext

Comment: Use a `PasswordEncoder` as `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, so you get Spring Security configured with a one-way encoder for your passwords. Passwords never should be decoded, that's one of security best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(this.dataSource)
.usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, active from user where email=?")
.authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?").passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
 }

@Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```